# Chaining function as promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm building a little node js data scrapping function inside a bigger app. I'm not so confortable with Javascript promises so please forgive my misunderstanding. Not sure that my title really frame my issue.

so I have this :

```
const getAxiosUrls = function() { axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gatable")
  .then(function (response) {
      return urls = response.data.rows.map( ([x, y, z]) => y )
  })}
```

and this :

```
const getNbShares = function() {
    Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
    const share = $('.nb-shares').html();
    let shareTuple = {};
    shareTuple[urls[index]] = share;
    return shareTuple;
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
}
```

and I would like to do this :

```
getAxiosUrls()
   .then(getNbShares)
   .then(res.json)
```

I've tried some stuff but most of the time I've got the following error : 
`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Also to be sure that my `getAxiosUrls` works correctly, I've done this

```
getAxiosUrls()
setTimeout(function() {console.log(urls)},5000)
```

and the log return me the response as expected. So what did I miss ?

Comment: `getAxiosUrls` and `getNbShares` doesn't return anything: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises

Comment: Besides the `return` issue, I guess you are not feeding the chain with the previous result such as `const getNbShares = function(urls){...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions `getAxiosUrls` and `getNbShares` don't return the promise. It should be

```
const getAxiosUrls = function() { 
    return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gatable")
      .then(function (response) {
          return urls = response.data.rows.map( ([x, y, z]) => y )
    })
}
```

and

```
const getNbShares = function(urls) {
    return Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
        .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
            const share = $('.nb-shares').html();
                let shareTuple = {};
                shareTuple[urls[index]] = share;
                return shareTuple;
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
}
```

As a side note: I would recommend removing the `.catch` in the `getNbShares` function, since this will cause the promise returned in this function to resolve to `undefined` in case of an error (you're not returning anything in the `catch` handler). It is often better to add error handling at the very end of your promise chain, unless there is something you can do to recover from the error.

Comment: so if I understand my function was returning something but not the promise. However I've read a lot of stuff about promise but I still don't really understand it. If a promise if nothing more than a value, my function was actually returning a value before you had the return...

Comment: Your function was not returning anything. Look at the `getAxiosUrls` function again, there is no return statement, hence `undefined` is returned, that is why you get the `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error, since you're calling `then` on the return value of `getAxiosUrls`.

Comment: In my mind the fact that I was getting the result I wanted when doing `getAxiosUrls() setTimeout(function() {console.log(urls)},5000)` would mean that I had something in return...

Comment: Keep in mind that the `axios.get` call is asynchronous. It **returns** immediately (a `promise`), but it **resolves** its result (the `urls`) only once the asynchronous call completes (that's when the `then` handlers are called).